# Can Visual Studio launch a secondary projects when Testing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I know a VS solution can have multiple projects started when I select "Run" or "Debug". But I couldn't find a way to launch two projects when I run tests. Imagine a functional test project, and an ASP.MVC Web project. The tests require the website started. When I click a test and select "Run Test" or "Debug test", I need it not only to launch the test host (vstest.console.exe) but also the web app host (iisexpress.exe), preferably both attached to debugger when "Debug".